# How can i remove previous route if i navigate from drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-android

When I navigate from drawer to any page and return back the drawer keeps open.
For example:
The drawer contains two-button and if I button one and then back, then second and then back.
Now if I press back button of android it will repeat all activities like in chrome.
Hope you get my point. If you need to know anything else from me. let me know

Comment: Even I added a button to navigate home. Now my active screen is home and if I press the home button from the drawer it opens again the home screen. And if press the android back button it also repeats the last activities.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
    void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => HomePage(),
        "/settings": (context) => SettingsPage(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
String _currentRoute = "/";

Widget buildDrawer(context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Home"),
            onTap: () => doRoute(context, '/'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Settings"),
            onTap: () => doRoute(context, '/settings'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void doRoute(BuildContext context, String name) {
  if (_currentRoute != name)
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, name);
  else
    Navigator.pop(context);

  _currentRoute = name;
}

// Page 1 (HomePage)
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home")),
      body: Container(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)),
      drawer: buildDrawer(context),
    );
  }
}

// Page 2 (SettingsPage)
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Settings")),
      body: Container(color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.5)),
      drawer: buildDrawer(context),
    );
  }
}
```